# React Native : Programmatically Changing Region sample code for android

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native-maps package but not getting correct output,
marker getting correctly moved but map is not updating accordingly

map is remain same position as its initial region, how can we change region on the fly?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  Dimensions,
  AppRegistry,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Animated,
} from 'react-native';

import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height;
const LATITUDE = 23.0123937;
const LONGITUDE = 72.5227731;
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO;
let id = 0;
let arb = 0.01;
function randomColor() {
  return `#${Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)}`;
}

export default class ReactProject extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      coordinate: new MapView.AnimatedRegion({
        latitude: LATITUDE + ((Math.random() - 0.5) * (LATITUDE_DELTA / 2)),
        longitude: LONGITUDE + ((Math.random() - 0.5) * (LONGITUDE_DELTA / 2)),
      }),
    };    
  } 


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          provider={this.props.provider}
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: LATITUDE,
            longitude: LONGITUDE,
            latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
            longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
          }}
        >
          <MapView.Marker.Animated
            coordinate={this.state.coordinate}
          />
        </MapView>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
           <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => this.setState(
              {
                coordinate: new MapView.AnimatedRegion({
                  latitude: LATITUDE + arb++,
                  longitude: LONGITUDE + arb++ ,
                })               
              }
            )}
            style={styles.bubble}
          >
            <Text>Animate</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
} 

ReactProject.propTypes = {
  provider: MapView.ProviderPropType,
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
  bubble: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)',
    paddingHorizontal: 18,
    paddingVertical: 12,
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
  latlng: {
    width: 200,
    alignItems: 'stretch',
  },
  button: {
    width: 80,
    paddingHorizontal: 12,
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginHorizontal: 10,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginVertical: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactProject', () => ReactProject);
```

Anyone can help out for this specific example, it would very helpful for me to stuck out.

Comment: Did you find de solution?

Comment: You have to pass updated coordinates to region prop of MapView component to update the region on fly